# CentOS: force files ownership after FTP upload

Tags: wordpress, apache, ftp, centos, ownership

here is my issue.

We are on a CentOS Linux VPS and we have a Wordpress web site.

Since Wordpress PID needs to run with the same PID of Apache and since I need an FTP user to connect sometimes, I have manually created an FTP user and then I have added [apache] user to the FTP user's group:

- mkdir -p /var/www/examples.com/html
- useradd MyFTPUser -d /var/www/examples.com/html -s /usr/sbin/nologin
- passwd MyFTPUser
- gpasswd -a apache MyFTPGroup
- gpasswd -a MyFTPUser MyFTPGroup
- chown –R apache:MyFTPGroup /var/www/examples.com/html

Now, the problem is that all the files uploaded via FTP have now [MyFTPUser:MyFTPGroup] ownership by default, instead of [apache:MyFTPGroup] (previously set via chown command).

Is it possible to force files ownership on a specific [user:group] via FTP uploading, for a specific [user]?

Not solving this problem means everytime that the FTP user will make some changes via FTP, Wordpress may stop to correctly work on some files.

Thanks a lot,
Etnok

Answer (score 0):

During file creation, you can manipulate the group part of [user:group] by either changing the primary group of the user Or by using 'newgrp' provided that the user belongs to the group your are trying to change to.

Basically, a user belongs to many groups and you are using one of them at a time. The same does not apply for the user part of [user:group]. What you could do is, to use 'chown' on all files on a particular folder every now and then.

Comment: Actually I want to exclude the way to manually run a 'chown" command every time the customer uploads something via FTP.

It doesn't really exist a way to let FTP uploads and Wordpress permissions live together?

Comment: owning is mutual exclusive, only one of them can own it at a time. However, you can add them to the same secondary group provided that the FTP user's primary group is that shared group. Or you will to use 'newgrp' to force the file ownership to be [FTPuser: sharedgroup]